# Moodle theme change based on user type

Tags: themes, moodle

I am using a Single Sign On technique from a Wordpress website,once the user logs on, they are automatically directed to the Moodle LMS namely 'courses/view.php?id=*relevant_id*'.

The $USER object already has the user type (called 'department' in this case) set up.

I want to do a theme switch based on this user type.

Something like:

if($USER->department == 'redTeam') {
  $theme = 'RedteamTheme';
}

My question is:
Where would I place this code snippet?
Does anyone know the exact syntax?

I have looked around Google for hours and I cannot get the syntax

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to do it in code.

In the lib folder you will need to amend 2 files:

pagelib and weblib.  The pagelib file is a lengthy extension so I won't paste that code here. If anyone wants it, they can contact me, I will happily share.

the weblib needs to have this added to it for theme switching to work:

```
  //create the function
    function _setTheme(){

        global $DB,$USER, $CFG, $THEME, $COURSE;//open abstraction layers
    //set the criteria for te switch in this case I used the department field, it can also      //be roles
        $getRole = $USER->department;

            if(!empty($getRole))  { //If the variable is not empty proceed with the switch 
                switch($getRole){

                case 'role1':
                $val = 'sky_high';     
                break;

                case 'role2':
                $val = 'leatherbound';     
                break;

}
    } else {
        //default theme
                    return 'leatherbound';
                }
                return $val;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how to contact you for the full pagelib and weblib code.  I have a friend who really would like to see how it is done.  Thank you!